# Add to JList and select element?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, actionlistener

I need some help to be able to add element to a JList and how to select element whith event.

This is my JList:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(430, 80));
```

This is part of my actionlistener that handle different buttons. It's here I want to use model.add("Name"); bot I get a red underline in Eclipse!?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
// New customer
if(event.getSource() == buttonNewCustomer && statusButtonNewCustomer)
{
String name = textInputName.getText();
String number = textInputPersonalNumber.getText();
boolean checkCustomerExist = customHandler.findCustomer(name, number); 

if(!checkCustomerExist) // If not true add new customer
{
customHandler.addCustomer(name, number); // Call method to add name
setTitle(title + "Kund: " + name); // Set new title
model.addElement(name);
}
}
}
```

Then I would preciate some help how I should select the element inside the JList? Should I use implements ActionListener to the class or a FrameHandler object? Thanks!

EDIT: My main problem that I can't solve is that the JList is inside the construcor and when I use model.add("name"); inside the constructor it works, but it's not working when I want to add something outside the constructor? I have read the tutorial several times, but can't find any help for this.

EDIT 2: The completet code. Probably some out of scope problem?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI4EX extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JButton buttonNewCustomer, buttonTerminate, buttonAddNewName, buttonAddNewSavingsAccount, buttonAddNewCreditAccount;
private JLabel textLabelName, textLabelPersonalNumber, textLabelNewName;
private JTextField textInputName, textInputPersonalNumber, textInputNewName;
private JPanel panelNewCustomer, panelQuit, panelNewAccount, panelChangeName, panelSelectCustomer;

private boolean statusButtonNewCustomer = true;
private boolean statusButton2 = true;
private boolean statusButtonAddNewName = true;

private String title = "Bank ";

// Create a customHandler object
CustomHandler customHandler = new CustomHandler();

// Main method to start program
public static void main(String[] args){
    GUI4EX frame = new GUI4EX();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
}

// Cunstructor
public GUI4EX(){
    // Create window
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(450,500);
    setLocation(400,100);
    setResizable(false);

    // Set layout to boxlayout
    Container container = getContentPane( );
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    JList list = new JList(model);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
    listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(430, 80));


    model.addElement("test");
    model.addElement("test");
    model.addElement("test");
    model.addElement("test");
    model.addElement("test");
    model.addElement("test");

    // Create jpanels
    panelNewCustomer = new JPanel();
    panelQuit = new JPanel();
    panelNewAccount = new JPanel();
    panelChangeName = new JPanel();
    panelSelectCustomer = new JPanel();

    // Create and add components - buttons
    buttonNewCustomer = new JButton("OK");
    buttonTerminate = new JButton("Avsluta");
    buttonAddNewName = new JButton("OK");
    buttonAddNewSavingsAccount = new JButton("Sparkonto");
    buttonAddNewCreditAccount = new JButton("Kreditkonto");

    // Create and add components - labels
    textLabelName = new JLabel("Namn");
    textLabelPersonalNumber = new JLabel("Personnummer");
    textLabelNewName = new JLabel("Nytt namn");
    //add(textLabel1);

    // Create and add components - textfields
    textInputName = new JTextField("");
    textInputPersonalNumber = new JTextField("");
    textInputName.setColumns(10);
    textInputPersonalNumber.setColumns(10);
    textInputNewName = new JTextField();
    textInputNewName.setColumns(20);

    // Add components to panel new customer
    panelNewCustomer.add(textLabelName);
    panelNewCustomer.add(textInputName);
    panelNewCustomer.add(textLabelPersonalNumber);
    panelNewCustomer.add(textInputPersonalNumber);
    panelNewCustomer.add(buttonNewCustomer);

    // Add components to panel to select customer
    panelSelectCustomer.add(listScroller);

    // Add components to panel new name
    panelChangeName.add(textLabelNewName);
    panelChangeName.add(textInputNewName);
    panelChangeName.add(buttonAddNewName);

    // Add components to panel new accounts
    panelNewAccount.add(buttonAddNewSavingsAccount);
    panelNewAccount.add(buttonAddNewCreditAccount);

    // Add components to panel quit
    panelQuit.add(buttonTerminate);

    // Set borders to jpanels
    panelNewCustomer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Skapa ny kund"));
    panelChangeName.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ändra namn"));
    panelNewAccount.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Skapa nytt konto"));
    panelQuit.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Avsluta programmet"));
    panelSelectCustomer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Välj kund"));

    // Add panels to window
    add(panelNewCustomer);
    add(panelSelectCustomer);
    add(panelChangeName);
    add(panelNewAccount);
    add(panelQuit);

    // Listener
    // FrameHandler handler = new FrameHandler();

    // Add listener to components
    //button1.addActionListener(handler);
    buttonNewCustomer.addActionListener(this);
    buttonAddNewName.addActionListener(this);
    buttonAddNewSavingsAccount.addActionListener(this);
    buttonAddNewCreditAccount.addActionListener(this);
    buttonTerminate.addActionListener(this);
}


//private class FrameHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        // New customer
        if(event.getSource() == buttonNewCustomer && statusButtonNewCustomer)
        {
            String name = textInputName.getText();
            String number = textInputPersonalNumber.getText();
            boolean checkCustomerExist = customHandler.findCustomer(name, number); // Check if customer exist

            if(!checkCustomerExist) // If not true add new customer
            {
                customHandler.addCustomer(name, number); // Call method to add name
                setTitle(title + "Kund: " + name); // Set new title
                model.addElement("name");
            }
        }

        // Change name
        if(event.getSource() == buttonAddNewName && statusButtonAddNewName)
        {
            String newName = textInputNewName.getText();
            customHandler.changeName(newName); // call method to change name
            setTitle(title + "Kund: " + newName);
        }

        // Create new savings account
        if(event.getSource() == buttonAddNewSavingsAccount)
        {
            customHandler.CreateNewSavingsAccount();    
        }

        // Create new credit account
        if(event.getSource() == buttonAddNewCreditAccount)
        {
            customHandler.CreateNewCreditAccount();
        }

        // Terminate program
        if(event.getSource()==buttonTerminate && statusButton2)
        {
            System.exit(3);
        }

    }

//}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lucky I am in a good mood. Here a very basic example, matching the code you provided. Type something in the textfield, hit the enter button and watch the list get populated.

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AddToJListDemo {

  private static JFrame createGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(  );

    final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    JList list = new JList( model );

    final JTextField input = new JTextField( 10 );
    input.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent aActionEvent ) {
        String text = input.getText();
        if ( text.length() > 0 ) {
          model.addElement( text );
          input.setText( "" );
        }
      }
    } );

    frame.add( list, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    frame.add( input, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    return frame;
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = createGUI();
        frame.setSize( 200,200 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Based on your full code, you must make the list a field in your `GUI4EX` class, similar to for example the `buttonNewCustomer` field

```
public class GUI4EX extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  //... all other field
  DefaultListModel model;

  //constructor
  public GUI4EX(){
    //all other code
    //DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel(); instantiate the field instead
    model = new DefaultListModel();
    JList list = new JList(model);
    //rest of your code
  }
}
```

This will make sure you can access the `model` in the `actionPerformed` method. But if you cannot figure out something this basic, you should not be creating GUIs but reading up on basic Java syntax and OO principles

Comment: Very kind of you, but my problem is why it doesn't work to add element to the JList when it is created in the constructor. If I add inside the constructor when the object is created it works, but I want to add from a method outside the constructor. It must be possible, but I'm learning java and I can't get it right? Help is preciated.

Comment: Then it is probably out-of-scope, but you did not post the relevant code. Probably you will have to store the list in a field so it can be accessed outside of the constructor. I suggest to read the [Classes and Objects tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) or post the relevant code (or at least the compile error)

Comment: Yes out-of-scope could be the problem. Could you show some example how to store the list in a field? I'm learning about classes and objects, but sometimes it's hard to understand it all. I try to add the complete code, but it's long

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help! Yes it's perhaps basic, but it's easy to forget details when you have been staring at the computer for a hole day. Anyway I'm greatful for the help! Hopefully I can solve the rest to be able to select the added element also. I'm learning :)